# React Native - adding different colors of shadows

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Good day! I'm creating a mobile application that I want to implement it with different color of shadows. But I tried to change hex code of colors but it does not change it is always black. How can I do it both Android and iOS platform? If impossible, suggest me any custom to create a different color of shadow. Thank you!

Comment: I already solved my problem. For the people who encounter or wants to change the color of shadow instead the default gray in android just use `react-native-shadow` library. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use shadows before, but I found someone suggest use cardview instead view to show shadow effect on both android and ios. And same suggest in many different places, maybe you can try to see. Hope it helps.(I'm not sure if it could change color from using background color)

```
<CardView
          cardElevation={3}
          cardMaxElevation={3}
          cornerRadius={3}
          style={{
            height: 60,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            margin: 20,
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff' //color?
          }}
          <Text>
              Elevation 
          </Text>
</CardView>
```

[someones answer on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2768#issuecomment-297976111)

[react-native-cardview](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview)

[example](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/react-native-cardview/blob/master/example/Example3.js)